# Can anyone explain this recursive function I can't understand how does it return anything?

Tags: c, recursion

I don't understand this recursive function how is it calculating the gcd can someone explain in detail how this recursive function returns the gcd?

```
#include <stdio.h>

long gcd(long, long);

int main() {
    long x, y, hcf, lcm;

    printf("Enter two integers\n");
    scanf("%ld%ld", &x, &y);

    hcf = gcd(x, y);
    lcm = (x*y)/hcf;

    printf("Greatest common divisor of %ld and %ld = %ld\n", x, y, hcf);
    printf("Least common multiple of %ld and %ld = %ld\n", x, y, lcm);

    return 0;
}

long gcd(long a, long b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    }
    else {
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try running it through a debugger and check every step? Did you try with pen and paper, either?

Comment: Have a look at [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read about this algorithm here: [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)

basically, if

```
a == bq + r
```

When `r` is the remainder of division `a` by `b` (so `0 <= r < b`)

then

```
gcd(a, b) == gcd(b, r)
```

notice that `a%b` is this remainder, `r`. because of that you can use recursion to calculate `gcd(a, b)`

when `r == 0`, it means that `a == bq`, or that `b` divides `a`.
thus, `b` is the greatest common divisor of `a, b`, and also for the originals `a, b`. at this point the recursive call will hold `b` as `a` and `0` as `b`, so its returns `a`.

hope that this explanation covers everything

Answer (score 0):

Visualization ...

```
// ...
long gcd(long a, long b) {
    fprintf(stderr, "INFO: called gcd(%ld, %ld)\n", a, b); // visualization
    if (b == 0) {
// ...
```